# Micro SD card not usable on phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, external-sd

I installed a Micro SD card on my Samsung Galaxy 3 phone. I had a few dozen songs on the card and everything was working fine. Then I shut down my phone, removed the SD card, hooked it up to my PC and loaded the card up with a few hundred MP3 files. When I reinstalled the SD card on my Android, things went wacky. I can see the SD card icon but when I go to `Settings > Storage`, the only option I see is the "Mount SD card" choice. When I click it, I get "SD card safe to remove".

Bottom line is that the card seems unusable on my phone but works fine on my PC. Ideas?

Comment: Did you un-mount the card before removing it?  Have you tried another card to verify the first is not damaged?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem numerous times and this is how I fix it.....

Take the SDcard and insert in card reader on PC. Use a partitioning program such as [GParted](http://gparted.org/download.php), which is open source. Have it scan and fix errors on the card. Using just the PC to scan and fix errors wont work right for your problem. Put it back in your Samsung and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You should reformat the card from within Settings -> Storage, then try copying the files again. Make sure you unmount the card before removal *even if you will be turning the device off to remove it*. I would highly suggest you transfer the files to the SD via the phone itself -- either by connecting the phone to the PC or using one of those apps that gives you access via wifi. SD cards in phones running Kitkat or later use exFAT, which allows for file/folder permissions. Moving a disk between different operating systems is a good way to mess up file attributes and ownership. The permissions are specific to the OS instance which set them, so a second OS reading the same disk wouldn't be able to make any meaningful sense of them.

Comment: First - Your assuming that the OP has KitKat installed.  Second - inserting the SD card in a PC will not mess up the file structure. Now if the OS was on the card and then inserted to run on another device, then file system structure can and most likely will become corrupted.......The main reason why people put the SD card in a PC is for speed

Answer (score -1):

Android like fat32 filesystem and fat32 like <4gb sdcard Windows like ntfs system but also familiar with fat32. My advice, format your SD with fat32 and remove it safely turn of your device mount your SD and power your device wait after boot and let us know

Comment: That is a bad idea. SD cards come pre-formatted, and reformatting them with an arbitrary file system will only exacerbate the problem. Most likely the card came pre-formatted with exFAT, and reformatting it to FAT32 will totally brick the card.

Comment: Thats not necessarily correct about bricking the card. With the proper PC program, such as HP USB Format Tool, you can reformat to any of the file systems without any hiccups.

Comment: I format my SD card almost everyday because i wrote raw image directly to SD, nothing happens so far to SD it works like charm